# How to update an XML TextView from other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have two fragments and I navigate by **swiping between them**. I want to update second fragment `TextView` from first fragment. Is it possibleto do that? Here's what I try to do but this doesn't worked to me.

```
public void updateOtherFragment(){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, null); //my second fragment xml file.
        TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textLog);

        tv.setText("Updated from first fragment " + info.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Google way for communication between fragments is to do that through the activity that hosts them.

The FirstFragment defines a callbacks interface that the activity must implement. When the activity gets a callback it can send the information through to the SecondFragment. Just read the example code below to make this more clear:

**FirstFragment.java**:

This fragment has a button, which when clicked sends a callback to its activity.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        result.findViewById(R.id.updateButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.updateButton:
                ((Callbacks) getActivity()).onUpdateLogtext("This is an update from FirstFragment");
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Hosting activity must implement Callbacks interface");
    }

    public interface Callbacks {
        void onUpdateLogtext(String text);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**:

This activity implements the `FirstFragment.Callbacks` interface in order to receive callbacks from FirstFragment. When it receives an `onUpdateLogtext` it just passes the data on to SecondFragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.Callbacks {

    private SecondFragment secondFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        secondFragment = (SecondFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.secondFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateLogtext(String text) {
        secondFragment.updateLogtext(text);
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment.java**:

This just provides a public method that sets the textview with new data. And this method is used by `MainActivity` when it gets a `onUpdateLogtext` callback from `FirstFragment`.

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView tv;

    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.textlog);
        return result;
    }

    public void updateLogtext(String text) {
        tv.setText(text);
    }
}
```